# Divide BigDecimal by int

Tags: java, math, integer, bigdecimal

I am trying to divide the change owed by 1 to figure out how many dollars are owned.  So if 3.60 is owed I want to divide that by 1 but I used BigDecimal to collect the change variable and can't figure out how to divide it by 1.

This is the code I have tried but it's not working.  I needed to use BigDecimal for round off errors but I also need to use that value with int values.

I am trying to input the amount of money owed for an item, say it's $5, then I am entering the amount received, say it's $8.70, I then need to figure out how to display how many dollars, quarters, dimes and cents I will give back.  So far I can't even figure out how to make it display 3 for dollars.  This is the code I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class CoinMachine {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int DollarValue = 1;

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Coin Machine\n");
    
    System.out.print("Enter the amount owed: ");
    BigDecimal amountOwed = in.nextBigDecimal();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the amount received: ");
    BigDecimal amountReceived = in.nextBigDecimal();
    
    if (amountReceived.compareTo(amountOwed) >= 0) {
        BigDecimal Change = (amountReceived.subtract(amountOwed));
        System.out.println("\nYour change today is $" + Change);
        
        BigDecimal Dollars = (.longValue(Change));
        System.out.println("Dollars Owed " + Dollars);
        
        
    
    
    }
    else {
        BigDecimal changeShort = (amountOwed.subtract(amountReceived));
        System.out.print("*** You did not provide enough money. You are $" + changeShort + " short. ***");
    }
    
    
    
    
    in.close();
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Dividing a number by 1 yields exactly the same number you started with.  So I don't think this will do anything at all.  But if you really must `BigDecimal same = Change.divide( BigDecimal.ONE );`

Comment: Hint: If you just want the integer portion of a `BigDecimal` I think `.longValue()` is a better bet.

Comment: I am trying to fix a rounding error and I can't do it with double.  I need to input the price of an item, how much was given and then how much they get back in dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and cents

Comment: Again, dividing by 1 does nothing.  That's just math.

Comment: I just updated the post.  I am trying to do what I stated above, any advice?

Comment: If you just want the dollars, I already gave you `longValue()`.

Comment: How are your constructing your BigDecimal Objects?

Comment: I just added all the code I have.  Can't even figure out how to get it to print the dollars with BigDecimal.  Been a 2 day process and have gotten no where....

Comment: Are you asking about the *compile error* at `BigDecimal Dollars = (.longValue(Change))`? If so, say so. Or is it just a typo in the question? If so, it is unclear what you're asking, or why you think division by 1 is going to accomplish anything. It isn't.

Answer (score 1):

### Define scale and rounding mode

```
    BigDecimal dollar = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal quarter = new BigDecimal("0.25");
    BigDecimal dime = new BigDecimal("0.10");
    
    BigDecimal change = new BigDecimal("3.60");
    BigDecimal numberOfDollars = change.divide(dollar, 0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(numberOfDollars);
```

Output is:

> 3

In the call to `divide()` I am specifying a scale of 0, that means, I want a result with no decimals after the decimal point. And I specify rounding down, so 3.6 is rounded down to 3.

The same trick works for quarters, dimes, nickels and cents. For example:

```
    change = change.subtract(numberOfDollars.multiply(dollar));
    BigDecimal numberOfQuarters = change.divide(quarter, 0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(numberOfQuarters);
```

> 2

Dimes, nickels and cents go in the same fashion.

Comment: Can you show me how to do nickels and cents as well?

Comment: `intValue()` may throw away a lot of information from the `BigDecimal`. Think twice. No, think three times.

Comment: I think it’s your turn now. You’re learning nothing from me doing all the work for you. Nickles and cents are similar, *very* similar. Go ahead and try. If unsuccessful, post a new question and ping me here, and I will take a look when I find time.

Comment: Thank you.  I just declared what nickel and cent will be as well 0.5 and 0.1, so now I will do the rest.  This is my first time using BigDecimal in depth, so I don't know all the commands for it yet.

Comment: @Sims Methods, not commands.

Comment: We’ve all been there. And I certainly don’t know all of them either. I may be more trained in reading [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) than you are now. It’s a good thing to practice.

Comment: If i remember US coins correctly, you will want 0.01 for cents.

Comment: Haha thank you, Ole, Yeah I meant 0.01.  Working on the quarters now, almost got it figured out, trying to subtract the Change minus the 3 dollars I would have already given to divine the 0.25 by the remaining.

Comment: Now I am being told by my professor that I have to use double to do it...  He is saying to fix the rounding "multiply it by 100 and put that in an integer, perhaps numberCents"

Comment: Oh, that’s a different question. Fortunately the professor cannot take away from you what you have learned about `BigDecimal` until now. Good luck with that challenge. Maybe see you around.

Comment: True.  Thank you, I think the idea is times it by 100 and then just work with it as a whole number and then convert it to a decimal at the end for the output.  That actually sounds easier.